# New Relic does not monitor my C# console application

Tags: configuration, console-application, newrelic

I follow these steps to install and configure New Relic for my non-IIS .NET application: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/instrumenting-non-iis-apps

> Enable the agent in the application's config file. In the config file, add a new appSetting with a key named NewRelic.AgentEnabled and a value of true.

I have all done but couldn't monitor my app on New Relic.

Have any offer?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow correctly all the steps newrelic has to work, make sure the following:

1. You activate the options in the red rectangles when you installed
   (see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/AroqR.jpg)
2. Create or modify app.config file of your application adding this (appSettings tag):

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key = "NewRelic.AppName" value="MYAPPLICATIONNAME" />
      </appSettings>
```

3. In the new relic config file, make sure you are renaming the "instrumentation" tag with the name you use in app.config (NewRelic.AppName value)

```html
<instrumentation>
    <applications>
            <application name="MYAPPLICATIONNAME" />
    </applications>
</instrumentation>
```

Restart you application (or your windows session lol)
I did this a lot of time and works for me.